# How to track form errors in Django?

Tags: django, forms, validationerror

how can I track form errors? Is there any concept within django or a plugin to track form errors?

I would like to understand why some of my website users have problems to submit a valid form. (By seeing the validation errors somewhere and the input)

Comment: There's nothing built-in Django for this, but I think there might be some JS libraries that might do such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using a [supported Django version](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions), then you can use the Form's [add_error](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error) method:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=4)

    def add_error(self, field, error):
        if field is not None:
            print('Error on field {}: {}'.format(field, error))
        else:
            print('Error on form: {}'.format(error))  # non field error
        super().add_error(field, error)

form = MyForm(data={'title': 'John Smith'})
form.is_valid()
```

You may replace the print statements by you preferred way to log (logging.info for instance).

Answer (score 0):

To do what you describe, code like the snippet below might help. You can then iterate over the form.errors in your template...

```
if form.is_valid():
    pass
    #actions
else:
    # form instance that has errors will be passed to the template
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```